# Understanding JSON and displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax request...

**Ajax**

```
function initUpdate()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    //grab id from link update_xxxx

    //get all gallery information
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/update',
        data: {"id": id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json)
        {

            //query was successful now populate form
            $("input[name='galleryName']").val(/*what goes here?*/);
        }
    });
}
```

That returns the following data

```
{
    "selected_gallery": [
        {
            "id": "4004",
            "name": "Album Proofer Sample Gallery",
            "clientRef": "205",
            "clientName": "Mike "
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I access "name" to insert in the val()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What have you tried?  I would think you could get to it via:

```
json.selected_gallery[0].name
```

`selected_gallery` is a JavaScript array, so you would access the first item in the collection using `[0]` in order access the first item's properties.

**UPDATE**

You could access other items in the array if they existed:

```
{
    "selected_gallery": [
        {
            "id": "4004",
            "name": "Album Proofer Sample Gallery",
            "clientRef": "205",
            "clientName": "Mike "
        },
        {
            "id": "5005",
            "name": "blah",
            "clientRef": "405",
            "clientName": "Dave "
        },
        {
            "id": "6006",
            "name": "boo",
            "clientRef": "605",
            "clientName": "Doug"
        }
    ]
}
```

To get the second item in the array, you'd reference it as:

`json.selected_gallery[1].name` (or `id` or `clientRef` or ...).  You can get to the third item via `json.selected_gallery[2].name`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `selected_gallery` is an array...you could have multiple instances of a `selected_gallery` object inside that array.  You access array elements using square bracket notation.

Comment: the square brackets after selected gallery indicate a javascript array.  the curly braces after the square hold the first item of that array, you could have more of those, but you only have 1 in this instance.  Arrays are 0 based, so you are accessing the first item [0] with that.